# Running/Loading multiple tensorflow models

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to load multiple models into the same module, however I am facing some issues. I have tried the with tf.variable.scope method, however I am having a hard time implementing this as I have not used the tf.session way of saving/loading the models.

Instead I am loading the two models by:

```
    # loading saved intent model
intent_net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(intent_train_x[0])])
intent_net = tflearn.fully_connected(intent_net, 8)
intent_net = tflearn.fully_connected(intent_net, 8)
intent_net = tflearn.fully_connected(intent_net, len(intent_train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
intent_net = tflearn.regression(intent_net)
intent_model = tflearn.DNN(intent_net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
intent_model.load('model1/intent_model.tflearn')

# loading saved question model
question_net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(question_train_x[0])])
question_net = tflearn.fully_connected(question_net, 8)
question_net = tflearn.fully_connected(question_net, 8)
question_net = tflearn.fully_connected(question_net, len(question_train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
question_net = tflearn.regression(question_net)
question_model = tflearn.DNN(question_net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
question_model.load('model2/question_model.tflearn')
```

I have created the two models in two different modules

```
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, show_metric=True)
model.save('model1/intent_model.tflearn')
```

When loading the two models in the same module, I get the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key Accuracy/Mean/moving_avg_1 not found in checkpoint
     [[{{node save_6/RestoreV2}}]]
```

How do I fix this?

This is for my seq2seq chatbot, so the first intent model identifies the intent, and if it identifies the input as a question, it will call the question model. Side question: I am planning on having 6-7 models after the different intents of the input, like question, command, greeting etc. Is this a dumb way to do it? The thought of splitting the model up in sub models is that I can later work more with the specific input given on the intent if I split it up in categories.